# Select phone number and e-mail ID in UITextView

Tags: ios5

I have a UITextView object. The text in UITextView has a phone number, mail link, a website link and also normal text messages. 
I used dataDetectorTypes to detect links and number. Links and number are detected using this method but I was only able to click website link. I want to click number and mail link also.

Note: I don't want to use webview for this.

Thanxs in advance,
Mayur

Comment: Could you please write some code here that you have used to detect data from UITextView?

Comment: Are you testing this on a device? The simulator may not support phone and mail links since the simulator doesn't have the Phone or Mail apps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating `UITextView` using UI then in `property window -> detection` section there is options available are

> **Links ,Addresses,Phone Numbers and Events**

select whatever you want

P.S if you want to enable this detection then do the following in `property window -> Behavior` section uncheck **Editable** option otherwise it will not detect